# A write action in a method does not seem to change the instance variable read in a thread in the same class

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have this JavaFX controller class where all the button action methods are present. In principle, my application is a client and establishes connection with a remote server. At the click of the "Connect" button, the ConnectButtonAction() method is invoked. As you can see in the code, here I assign the boolean variable "connect" to true ( connObject.connect() returns true if a connection request is accepted by the server successfully).

The problem is the object field "connect" is not changed to TRUE after connection. In my code, you can see I run a thread in my controller class. In the overridden run() method, I print the "connect" variable. Here, the "connect" variable is printed FALSE even after the connection is made to the server.

My question is why is the instance variable (is this the right term?) "connect" not changed to TRUE after connection is made in the ConnectButtonAction() method?

```
public class PrimaryWindowController implements Initializable, Runnable {

//connect tab FXML ids
@FXML
private Label alertLabel;
@FXML
private ToggleButton TCPbutton, UDPbutton;
@FXML
private Button connectButton;
@FXML
private Circle circle;
@FXML 
private TextField targetIP, port;

//pin console FXML ids
@FXML
private Button setButton, reset1Button, addButton, reset2Button, deleteButton;

//lower panel FXML ids
@FXML
private Circle statusCircle;
private Label humidity, pressure, lux, longitude, latitude, temperature, battery;

//non-FXML variables
private TCPConnect connObject;
private Thread run;
private volatile boolean connect = false;

public PrimaryWindowController()
{

}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(connect == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Connect: " + connect);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrimaryWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        if(connect == true)
        {
            System.out.println("run is running");

            try {
                    BufferedReader reader;
                    String line;
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connObject.client().getInputStream()));

                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line.split(",")[0]);
                        System.out.println(line.split(",")[1]);
                        humidity.setText("Humidity: " + line.split(",")[1] + "%");
                        System.out.println(line.split(",")[2]);
                        latitude.setText("Latitude: " + line.split(",")[2]);
                    }


                if(connObject.getInputStreamRead() == -1)
                {
                    connectButton.setDisable(false);
                    targetIP.setDisable(false);
                    circle.setFill(Color.RED);
                    statusCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
                    connect = false;

                    alertLabel.setVisible(true);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PrimaryWindowController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void show(String line)
{
    if(line.startsWith("(humidity)"))
    {
        humidity.setText("Humidity: " + line.substring(10) + "%");
    }
    else if(line.startsWith("(latitude)"))
    {
        latitude.setText("Latitude: " + line.substring(10));
    }
}

@FXML
private void TCPButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{
    UDPbutton.setDisable(true);
}

@FXML
private void UDPButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{
    TCPbutton.setDisable(true);
}


@FXML
private void ConnectButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    connObject = new TCPConnect(targetIP.getText(), Integer.parseInt(port.getText()));

    connect = connObject.connect();
    System.out.println(connect);

    if(connect)
    {
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        statusCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        connectButton.setDisable(true);
        targetIP.setDisable(true);
        port.setDisable(true);

        alertLabel.setVisible(false);
    }
}

//the button actions for pin console tab
@FXML
private void setButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

}

@FXML
private void reset1ButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

}

@FXML
private void addButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

}

@FXML
private void reset2ButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

}

@FXML
private void deleteButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
{

}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    run = new Thread(new PrimaryWindowController());
    run.start();
}
```

}

Comment: You have two instances of PrimaryWindowController: one used as a graphical component, and one used as a Runnable by the spawned thread. The graphical component updates its flag, but that won't change the flag of the one used by the thread. Also, please name the variable `connected` rather than `connect`, respect the Java naming conventions (methods never start with an uppercase letter), and don't compare boolean variable to true and false: just use `if (connected)` or `if (!connected)`.

Comment: Calling Node methods (setText, setDisable, setVisible, etc.) from outside of the [application thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) is going to cause problems.  Use Platform.runLater, or Task or Service.